# Angular 5 Typescript - Save Local JSON File

Tags: json, file, typescript, save, angular5

Im trying to make a local app, for myself and save everything in json localy.
i have this Posts Interface and array with data build up:

```
this.p = [{
      posts:{
        id: 'hey man',
        title:     'awdwada',
        description: 'awdawdaw',
        commands: {
            title: 'dawdawdawd',
            description: 'awdawda',
            note: 'wadadaw',
        }
      }

    }
    ];
     const r =  JSON.stringify(this.p);
      console.log(r);
```

how can i save this into a json file?

Comment: You send it to a backend REST service and the backend service saves it.

Comment: thats not local at all

Comment: It is if your REST server runs on your own computer. Isn't that the case? If it isn't, how is it a "local app"?

Comment: reading and writing json only

Comment: So "local" means "reading and writing json only"? That's quite a new definition for "local". Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, and how you intend to deploy and run the app, in your question.

Comment: Refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage

Answer (score -1):

```
posting()      
   {
     this.http.post<any>(this.baseurl).map(res:Response=>{res.json();});
   }
ngOnInit()   
   {
     this.appService.posting().subscribe(data=>this.p=data);
   }
```

Comment: If some how database is a local so http may or may not be supported and you have to add header it will add easily, Thank you